# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLInputElement.calcularMontos (main.js:63)

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda con el error ya mencionado aca les dejo el codigo de JavaScript
Ya que no me deja insertar el html o el css por que me aparece que es mucho codigo asi que si me pueden ayudar estaria muy agradecido. Para aclarar todas las variable que aparecen ya esta declaradas nada mas que no me deja insertar mas codigo.

````
    "use strict";
    var regalo = document.getElementById('regalo');
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        calcular.addEventListener('click', calcularMontos);

        function calcularMontos(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (regalo.value === '') {
                alert("Debes elegir un regalo");
                regalo.focus();
            } else {
                var boletosDia = parseInt(pase_dia.value, 10) || 0,
                    boletos2Dias = parseInt(pase_dosdias.value, 10) || 0,
                    boletoCompleto = parseInt(pase_completo.value, 10) || 0,
                    cantCamisas = parseInt(camisas.value, 10) || 0,
                    cantEtiquetas = parseInt(etiquetas.value, 10) || 0;


                var totalPagar = (boletosDia * 30) + (boletos2Dias * 45) + (boletoCompleto * 50) + ((cantCamisas * 10) * .93) + (cantEtiquetas * 2);

                var listadoProductos = [];

                if (boletosDia >= 1) {
                    listadoProductos.push(boletosDia + ' Pases por dia');
                }
                if (boletos2Dias >= 1) {
                    listadoProductos.push(boletos2Dias + ' Pases por dos dias');
                }
                if (boletoCompleto >= 1) {
                    listadoProductos.push(boletoCompleto + ' Pases completos');
                }
                if (cantCamisas >= 1) {
                    listadoProductos.push(cantCamisas + ' Camisas');
                }
                if (cantEtiquetas >= 1) {
                    listadoProductos.push(cantEtiquetas + ' Etiquetas');
                }

                var lista_productos = document.querySelector('lista_productos');

                lista_productos.innerHTML = ''; // ahí me da error //
                for (var i = 0; i < listadoProductos.length; i++) {
                    lista_productos.innerHTML += listadoProductos[i] + '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }); // DOM CONTENT LOADED
})(); ```
````

Comment: Me sale este error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.calcularMontos (main.js:63)"

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca tu código como texto, no has aportado nada para que te puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: @MateoDiBenedetto La URL que colocaste apunta a tu host local (127.0.0.1 o localhost), lo que quiere decir que solo puede ser consultada en tu equipo por que el servidor web solo está corriendo ahí. Proporciona la parte de tu código que representa el problema y con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos

Answer (score 0):

El error está en esta línea, dado que esperas que el método `querySelector` te devuelva un nodo HTML.

```javascript
var lista_productos = document.querySelector('lista_productos');
```

La solución está en revisar tu selector (El parámetro que le pasas a la función) para asegurarte de que el elemento HTML existe.

Lo más probable es que hayas omitidor un `#` al inicio del selector.

```javascript
var lista_productos = document.querySelector('#lista_productos');
```

El signo `#`, sirve para referirse a identificadores únicos en html, tales como:

```html
<div id="lista_productos"><div>
```

Otra posibilidad es que hayas omitido un punto.

```javascript
var lista_productos = document.querySelector('.lista_productos');
```

Así, la función te regresará el primer elemento que encuentre con la clase `lista_productos`.

```html
<div class="lista_productos"><div>
```